# Create Purchase receipt from Purchase order through web service

Tags: acumatica

We are trying to create a PO receipt document that is linked to a PO document. Below is the code, but after submitting the selection of PO lines, the webservice not returning any results. Later it gives an execution time out exception.

```
        apitest.Screen context = BuisnessLogicACU.context;
        PO302000Content PORcptSchema;
        try
        {
            PORcptSchema = context.PO302000GetSchema();
        }
        catch
        {
            BuisnessLogicACU.contextLogin();
            PORcptSchema = context.PO302000GetSchema();
        }
        PORcptSchema.Actions.AddPOOrderLine2.Commit = true;
       //header            
            AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] Document = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[]
            {                    
                PORcptSchema.Actions.Insert,
                 new Value
                {
                    Value = BPCode,
                    LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.Vendor,
                    Commit = true
                },
                 new Value
                {
                    Value = BPRefNbr ,
                    LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.VendorRef
                },
                 new Value
                {
                    Value = PostDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)PostDate.Value).ToLongDateString() : "",
                    LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.Date
                },                   
                 new Value
                {
                    Value = DocDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)DocDate.Value).ToLongDateString() : "",
                    LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.Date
                },
                 new Value
                {
                    Value = Description,
                    LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.NoteText
                },
                new Value
                {
                    Value = "POS Doc " + DocNum,
                    LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.VendorRef
                },

            };



//set the dialog answer
            var dgAnswer = new Command[]
                        { new Value 
                            {
                                Value = "OK", 
                                LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer, 
                                Commit = true 
                            }
                        };
            Document = Document.Concat(dgAnswer).ToArray();


 //select lines
            foreach (POReceiptLine line in POReceiptlines.OrderBy(x => x.LineNum))
            {
                AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] Docline = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[]
                {                   
                    new Key
                    {
                        ObjectName = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.OrderNbr.ObjectName,
                        FieldName = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.OrderNbr.FieldName,
                        Value = "='" + line.BaseDocNum + "'"
                    },
                    new Key
                    {
                        ObjectName = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.LineNbr.ObjectName,
                        FieldName = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.LineNbr.FieldName,
                        Value = "='" + line.BaseLineNum + "'"
                    },              
                    new Value 
                    {
                        Value = "True", 
                        LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.Selected, 
                        Commit = true 
                    }  
                };
                Document = Document.Concat(Docline).ToArray();
            }

  //Add PO line. 
            var addPOLine = new Command[]
                        { 
                            PORcptSchema.Actions.AddPOOrderLine2,

                            ////get back the added lines in the grid
                            PORcptSchema.DocumentDetails.POOrderNbr,
                            PORcptSchema.DocumentDetails.POLineNbr
                        };
            Document = Document.Concat(addPOLine).ToArray();

            var receiptLines = context.PO302000Submit(Document);
//update quantity..
            //check CreateShipment() in webservice demo
            List<Command> commandList = new List<Command>();
            for (int index = 0; index < receiptLines.Length; index++)
            {
                commandList.Add(new Value
                {
                    Value = index.ToString(),
                    LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.RowNumber
                });

                POReceiptLine line = POReceiptlines.Where(x => x.BaseDocNum == receiptLines[index].DocumentDetails.POOrderNbr.Value && x.BaseLineNum.ToString() == receiptLines[index].DocumentDetails.POLineNbr.Value).FirstOrDefault();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    commandList.Add(new Value
                    {
                        Value = line.Qty.ToString(),
                        LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentDetails.ReceiptQty,
                        Commit = index < receiptLines.Length - 1
                    });
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("Matching POS Rcpt line not found.");
            }


            //save
            AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] save = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] {
                        PORcptSchema.Actions.Save
                    };
            Document = Document.Concat(save).ToArray();

            //SAVING And get the document nbr
            AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] Output = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] {                 
                PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.Type,
                PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.ReceiptNbr               
            };
            Document = Document.Concat(Output).ToArray();

           var POReceipt = context.PO302000Submit(Document)[0];
```

After this particular line, web service is not returning any results. Anyone can assist on this?

**var receiptLines = context.PO302000Submit(Document);**

Comment: I just want to point out that when creating your Document commands array, your third and seventh command are both setting value to the VendorRef Field. The same thing happens with your fourth and fifth command who are both setting a value to the Date Field.

Comment: Yea, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@samol518's sample assisted me to resolve. I am posting the full code, if anyone later needs it

the below code will add lines from PO, change quantity and save the PO receipt.

```
public void createAcuPR()
    {

        apitest.Screen context = BuisnessLogicACU.context;
        PO302000Content PORcptSchema;
        try
        {
            PORcptSchema = context.PO302000GetSchema();
        }
        catch
        {
            BuisnessLogicACU.contextLogin();
            PORcptSchema = context.PO302000GetSchema();
        }
        var addPOLineWithCommit = PORcptSchema.Actions.AddPOOrderLine;
        addPOLineWithCommit.Commit = true;

        //somehow if there is a second document then it goes to update mode
        context.PO302000Submit(new Command[] { PORcptSchema.Actions.Insert });

        //header            
        AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] Document = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[]
        {                
            PORcptSchema.Actions.Insert,
             new Value
            {
                Value = BPCode,
                LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.Vendor,
                Commit = true
            },
             new Value
            {
                Value = BPRefNbr ,
                LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.VendorRef
            },
             new Value
            {
                Value = PostDate.HasValue ? ((DateTime)PostDate.Value).ToLongDateString() : "",
                LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.Date
            },               
             new Value
            {
                Value = "POS Doc " + DocNum + "-" + Description,
                LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.NoteText
            }                               
        };

        //set the dialog answer
        var dgAnswer = new Command[]
                    { new Value 
                        {
                            Value = "OK", 
                            LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer, 
                            Commit = true 
                        }
                    };
        Document = Document.Concat(dgAnswer).ToArray();

        //select lines from smart panel
        foreach (POReceiptLine line in POReceiptlines.OrderBy(x => x.LineNum))
        {
            AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] Docline = new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[]
            {                   
                new Key
                {
                    ObjectName = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.OrderNbr.ObjectName,
                    FieldName = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.OrderNbr.FieldName,
                    Value = "='" + line.BaseDocNum + "'"
                },
                new Key
                {
                    ObjectName = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.LineNbr.ObjectName,
                    FieldName = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.LineNbr.FieldName,
                    Value = "='" + line.BaseLineNum + "'"
                },              
                new Value 
                {
                    Value = "True", 
                    LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.Selected, 
                    Commit = true 
                }  
            };
            Document = Document.Concat(Docline).ToArray();
        }


        //Add PO line and retrive back the added lines.
        var addPOLine = new Command[]
                    {                             
                        addPOLineWithCommit,
                        ////get back the added lines in the grid
                        PORcptSchema.DocumentDetails.POOrderNbr,
                        PORcptSchema.DocumentDetails.POLineNbr
                    };
        Document = Document.Concat(addPOLine).ToArray();

        var receiptLines = context.PO302000Submit(Document);

        //update quantity..           
        List<Command> commandList = new List<Command>();
        for (int index = 0; index < receiptLines.Length; index++)
        {
            commandList.Add(new Value
            {
                Value = index.ToString(),
                LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.RowNumber
            });

            POReceiptLine line = POReceiptlines.Where(x => x.BaseDocNum == receiptLines[index].DocumentDetails.POOrderNbr.Value && x.BaseLineNum.ToString() == receiptLines[index].DocumentDetails.POLineNbr.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            if (line != null)
            {
                commandList.Add(new Value
                {
                    Value = line.Qty.ToString(),
                    LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.DocumentDetails.ReceiptQty,
                    Commit = index < receiptLines.Length - 1
                });
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Matching POS Rcpt line not found.");
        }

        //save
        commandList.AddRange(
                    //SAVING And get the document nbr
                   new AcumaticaInterface.apitest.Command[] {   
                        PORcptSchema.Actions.Save,
                        PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.Type,
                        PORcptSchema.DocumentSummary.ReceiptNbr               
        });


        var POReceipt = context.PO302000Submit(commandList.ToArray())[0];           
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution was tested using Acumatica version 6.00.1596.

I found that to return the value of the Purchase Order Lines, you do not need to do a foreach.

After setting the value for the summary and removing the deuplicate here is what I use to get back the POLines.

```
var selectPOLine = new Command[]
{
    new Value
    {
        Value = "OK",
        LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer,
        Commit = true
    },
    addPOLineWithCommit,
    new Value
    {
        LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLinePOSelection.OrderNbr,
        Value = "PO000451"
    },
    new Value
    {
        Value = "True",
        LinkedCommand = PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.Selected,
    },
    PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.InventoryID,
    PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.LineDescription,
    PORcptSchema.AddPurchaseOrderLine.LineType,
};
```

With "addPOLineWithCommit" define as

```
var addPOLineWithCommit = PORcptSchema.Actions.AddPOOrderLine;
addPOLineWithCommit.Commit = true;
```

Using these the line :
**var receiptLines = context.PO302000Submit(Document);**
was returning me some information on available lines.

Comment: some part of your code helped to resolve the issue. i will post the full working code.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working, Receipt is creating but new created receipt is not generated for newley generated Purchase order, this receipt is generated for old any PO

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30556461)